# User login with working hours restriction in MVC3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, entity-framework-4, autofac

I am looking of good ways of restricting user login during off-work hours in MVC3 application.

I have customized authorize filter in place in application so thinking of putting in a module for time check.

I also want to give grace period of say 30 mins (configurable) to user after end time.

Code snippet would be really very helpful.

**Edit:**
working hours and grace period would be stored in SQL server for Monday to Sunday and would be assigned to each user.

So also please suggest a way to input these details. I do have system administrator page where I can update user table in sql server. using jquery slider would be good approach I think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have customized authorize filter in place in application so thinking
>   of putting in a module for time check

Yeah, that seems like a very good approach:

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var now = DateTime.Now;
        // TODO: you probably want to read those values from a config file 
        // to avoid hardcoding them
        if (now.Hour > 8 && now.Hour < 20)
        {
            return base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
        }

        // we are outside of standard working hours => deny authorization
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this part in your xml file. Security purposes can be configure in your xml I guess

Comment: do you mean putting working hours in xml or grace period or users?